# Find records where modulo is greater than some number

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In mongodb you can find records where field%X=Y :

```
db.collection.find({
 field: {
  $mod: [X, Y]
 }
})
```

I need $mod to be greater than Y. I've tried this:

```
db.collection.find({
 field: {
  $mod: [X, {
   $gt: Y
  }]
 }
})
```

but no effects. How can i find this records? Any ideas?

Regards,
Mateusz

Comment: I know that i can do db.collection.find({$where:"this.field%X>Y"}) but it's really more "expensive"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From v2.4 mongodb changed JavaScript engine to V8, promissing better performance and concurrency.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-javascript/

I think $where operator is quite appropriate unless "X" is fixed in your app. With static "X" it might be worth having another precomputed field {field % X}

Comment: X != const so I can't make precomputed field which you mentioned. This query will be executed on ~20*10^6 records db, do you really think that using $where is good decision?

Comment: Well. If it is really not possible to prepare your collection for fixed number of these queries, try running query with aggregation framework and compare performance to $where operator. Aggregation framework should handle batches of records in parallel. So there possibly could be performance increase. Otherwise I don't know what do you really expect from Mongodb